# MYSQL Update within Select - Updating a row multiple times while concating row

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've searched and searched, but I can't quite find the answer to this question.

Say I have two tables.

Table A is from my new table, and has id, and tags.
Table B is from my old database, and has tag_id and tag_text.

I need to do something like this.

```
UPDATE A,B
SET A.tags = CONCAT(A.tags, B.tag_text)
WHERE A.id IN
    (SELECT tag_id FROM B where B.category_id = 'video')
```

I am trying to loop through each item in A, check if its id matches a tag_id in B, and if it does, concat it with a "," in between for tags in A.

For the life of me, I know I've done this before, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please give me more information so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an `INNER JOIN` between the `A` and `B` tables?

```
UPDATE A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.tag_id
SET A.tags = CONCAT(A.tags, B.tag_text)
WHERE B.category_id = 'video'
```

Comment: It didn't. It only affected 905 rows. There are over 5000 in table B and over 1100 in table A.

Comment: Please show us the `SELECT` query you would use to identify the records you want to update.  Thanks.